# How Do I Use XPath To Select Immediate Sibling of Element That Has Specific innerText?

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

Here is my sample source HTML:

```html
<!-- Many other elements above this -->

<div class="emf-div-field">
    <span style="width:175px">
        <input class="validate[required]" style="width:100%" value="" id="element_2" name="element_2" type="text">
        <label for="element_2" class="emf-bottom-label emf-text-center">First</label>
    </span>

    <span style="width:125px">              
        <input class="validate[optional]" style="width:100%" value="" id="element_6" name="element_6" type="text">
        <label for="element_6" class="emf-bottom-label emf-text-center">Middle</label>
    </span>

    <span style="width:175px">
        <input class="validate[required]" style="width:100%" value="" id="element_3" name="element_3" type="text">
        <label for="element_3" class="emf-bottom-label emf-text-center">Last</label>
    </span>

</div>

<!-- Many other elements below this -->
```

I need the XPath to select the `<input>` element just prior to the `<label>` element whose innerText is "First".  The `<input>` element is always a sibling of the `<label>` element.

It needs to be a relative selection, based on the `<label>` innerText because in general these statements could be at many different levels.

I have tried this (and many other variations), but none have worked:

`//input[preceding-sibling::label[text() = "First"]]`

Thanks.

Comment: Sadly, most CSS innertext selectors have been removed from the spec, most of it has to be done via JQuery or JS now !

Comment: Do you have any control over the `<label>` tag? Can you make it: `<label for="element_2" class="emf-bottom-label emf-text-center" text="First">First</label>` and use the css selector `div span input+label[text="First"] {
  color: red;
}` ?

Comment: Why did someone give my question a negative vote???  If you did it, please have the guts and integrity to post your reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make it too complicated. Just use

```
//span[label='First']/input
```

But if you really need a path relative to the `label` element, use

```
//label[.='First']/preceding-sibling::input[1]
```

Comment: Thanks, @zx485!  That is perfect.    I have another more complicated XPath question, but I'm make a separate question.